# Sqlite Create item from Listener :

Tags: android, sqlite, listener, chat, onclicklistener

goodnight,

I have a problem when listening to a package, intercept, and I see the text and all, but to use ". CreateMessage ()" inside the Listener "does not work"

If it works when i onclick, but when I hear the onlistener.

I'm wrong concepts Listeners? I need something to record with (observer)?

This is my code :

```
// LISTEN MESSAGES : 
PacketFilter filter = new MessageTypeFilter(Message.Type.groupchat);
connect.getConnection().addPacketListener(new PacketListener(){
    @Override
    public void processPacket(Packet packet){
        Message message = (Message) packet;
        if (message.getBody() != null){
            //messageArray.add(message.getBody());
            //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                   
            addNewMessage(new Messages(message.getBody(), false));
            try{
                // HERE ! debug CORRECT and use this linea.
                // BUT sqlite not user .createMessage() 
                UserDataAccesObject.createMessage(id, id, message.getBody(),CurrentUsernameClick ,usernameSession , time);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Xavii - ERROR Create Listen> ", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}, filter);
```

Comment: Any idea? is to urgent, I read : "https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/running-sync-adapter.html" is interesting but I don't know how work, but I don't know if is correct for solve my problem.

Comment: is similar but not work ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351368/loader-not-loading-data-when-sqlite-data-changes

Comment: I do not find the solution for this problem. 
within the "listener" I can not save anything in sqlite 
it is very urgent.

Comment: I tried runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {@Override public void run(){ //here code}}); but run always ... I get 3 or 4 identical messages, not work correct, I need get 1 message different of another... simple

Comment: you can use broadcast receiver for updating your UI. After receiving message in packet listener Context.sendBroadcast(intent), and in activity or fragment where you want to show messages call Context.registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter)